# How to join two query string in response.xpath using scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have to perform same operation on cat1 & act2, I there any who to pass both query strings to same Xpath extractor or to to combine both query strings ??

```
cat1 = response.xpath("//*[@id='linkControl']")
cat2=response.xpath("//*[@id='form1']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[*]/a")
```

Comment: You can use or operator '|' in regexp

Comment: post the HTML code

Comment: @stamaimer am i supposed to use lke this ??
response.xpath("//*[@id='linkControl']" | "//*[@id='form1']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[*]/a")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath has [union operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256074(v=vs.110).aspx) (`|`) which you can use :

```
xpath1 = "//*[@id='linkControl']"
xpath2 = "//*[@id='form1']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[*]/a"
result = response.xpath(xpath1 + " | " + xpath2)
```

Comment: when i test in firebug it works fine, but in scrapy code it only extract corresponding to xpath1 .
any suggestion ??

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use CSS Selectors instead of Xpaths.

```
cat1 = response.xpath("#linkControl")
cat2=response.xpath("#form1 div::nth-child(2) div::nth-child(2) div::nth-child(2) div div a")
```

And to combine both of them use `,` (commma)

```
cat1 = response.xpath("#linkControl, #form1 div::nth-child(2) div::nth-child(2) div::nth-child(2) div div a")
cat2=response.xpath("#linkControl, #form1 div::nth-child(2) div::nth-child(2) div::nth-child(2) div div a")
```